# Make a div visible inside a div with overflow hidden and position relative

Tags: html, css, position

I have a given div containers which I cannot change (actually there are more containers, but I'll use only 2 for this example). The containers have these css rules  :

```
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

Inside, I have a div that I want to position exactly where it already is, but need to make it visible.

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ewvxkns3/4/)

I know that if, I'll set `position: absolute` to the inner div and `position: auto or unset` to the containers, it will work, but unfortunately I can't change the containers at all.

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/6rLak1g1/1/) of how I want it to look like. Can I achieve this without changing the containers?

Comment: You say you "can't change the containers at all." Does that mean you can't edit the CSS, HTML, both? Can't add additional CSS?

Comment: I can access the elements, but changing rules can break the entire component, and since it's not a component I own I'm looking for a way to overcome the problem without refactoring the entire component.